# Laravel database and controller issues

Tags: php, database, laravel, controller

I'm creating a website by using Laravel 5.3. There is a problems about database connection. I have 2 independent tables called languages and documents 
when I retrieve data from these tables the problems happen.
Here is my code in language controller

```
use App\Languages;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class LanguageController extends Controller {
    public function getLanName(){
        $lans = Languages::all();
        return view('index',compact('lans'));
    }
}
```

and here is the code of language model

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Languages extends Model{
    protected  $table = 'languages';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected  $primaryKey = 'lan_id';
}
```

the Document controller and model are same as language

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Documents;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class DocumentController extends Controller{
    public function getDocName(){
        $docs = Documents::all();
            return view('index',compact('docs'));

    }
}
```

and this is my route and  some of html in the view:

```
Route::get('/',['uses' => 'DocumentController@getDocName']);
Route::get('/',['uses' => 'LanguageController@getLanName']);

        <select >
                <option  >Select Document</option>
                @foreach($docs as $doc)
                    <option value="{{$doc->docName}}">{{$doc->docName}}    </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>  
            <select>
                <option >Select Language</option>
                @foreach($lans as $lan)
                    <option value="{{$lan->language}}">{{$lan->language}}</option>
                @endforeach
        </select>
```

I can only retrieve either language or document. If I comment language or document, the other one works well.Can't I use two controller in same route?

Many Thanks to help..

Comment: Can you add also `getDocName` function?

Comment: I edited and add getDocName function. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this isnt possible. You can not bind two separate controllers to a single **Route**. One could even argue that it is very bad practice. You could create something like an OverviewController for this single page, and just call the 2 models in your controller method.

You could also use a **Repository**, answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26092119

Comment: namespace App;
use App\Languages;
use App\Documents;
class DataRepository{
    public function getData(){
        return Documents::all();
    }
    public function getAllLang(){
        return Languages::all();
    }
}