# how to call two functions by one route in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-route

I want to get 2 functions by 1 route to view

I tried like this but not working

```
Route::post('prospect', ['ProspectController@store' , 
                         'course_controller@show_details']);
```

Comment: Write code to all show details function at the end of store function

Comment: try it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091998/laravel-how-to-use-2-controllers-in-1-route

Comment: Not possible. Check link above.

Comment: or may be create an ajax to get data from two functions on load.

Comment: You can create one master method and based on your condition you can show different views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
Route::get('prospect', 'course_controller@show_details');
Route::post('prospect', 'ProspectController@store');
```

If you want to show the `prospect` after it has been stored, why not just return it in `ProspectController@store` ?

If you want to follow Restful API design :

```
 Route::post('prospect', 'ProspectController@store'); // return created prospect here

 Route::get('prospect/{id}', 'ProspectController@show');
```

Answer (score 0):

better to used [redirect to controller action](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects#redirecting-controller-actions)

> ```
> try this way
> ```

```
Route::post('prospect', 'ProspectController@store'); //use only one method
```

now add in line in `ProspectController` in `store` method  if you want to use redirect method

```
   return redirect()->action('HomeController@index');
```

otherwise use call method only like this way..

```
 app('App\Http\Controllers\course_controller')->show_details();
```

otherway used like that

```
 app(course_controller::class)->show_details();
```

or directly create object like that

```
(new  App\Http\Controllers\course_controller())->show_details();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code:

```
Route::post('prospect','ProspectController@store');

public function store(Request $request)
{
    if($request->something == 'something'):
       Self::showDetail();
    else:
      // Continue store method

    endif;
}

public static function showDetail(){

}
```

Comment: @Jazim Max This is perfect & right answer as per your question. Please accept this as a answer of question.